# Storing Auth Tokens that are used by Cloud Run services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an app running in a Cloud Run container, that communicates with multiple 3rd parties and therefore needs to provide auth headers to access their data. For some services, this auth token will need to be refreshed after a set time.

What is the best way to store these tokens so that they are shared across all instances of my cloud run containers, and so that if it needs to be updated multiple containers won't try to update it at once.

I thought about storing the token in a database, but then this increases read times and greater costs so isn't a very efficient method.

I know Memorycache could be used but would like to know if there are any other recommended ways.

Comment: Memorystore is the fastest solution that you can have. Firestore/datastore and the less expensive (if you have less than 30k reads/writes per day). You can also use secret manager with a naming convention for each customer to store and retrieve the secret (don't forget that auth token are secrets and you must ensure the security first!)

Comment: Your question lacks details to create a good answer. What is the cost (CPU time) to generate an auth token? What is the cost to store and access tokens in Memorystore? Cloud Run is a very low-cost service. Memorystore has minimum costs. How does your design determine the leader so that tokens are not recreated by multiple services? Where is the state information stored required to generate tokens? Cloud Run is a stateless service. When you need state (storing auth tokens), it is then probably not the best service if pricing was your reason for selecting Cloud Run.